# Bounded class as parameter

Tags: java, generics, bounded-types

I'm driving crazy with the bounded class...

I defined such a method :

```
protected <X> DataAccessResult<List<X>> executeQuery(final String query, final Class<X> elementType,Object... args)
```

And I want to call it with the following arguments:
Query : a SQL query, what it actually does doesn't matter
elementType : I need something like `Map<String,Object>.class`, because what I need to get is a `DataAccessResult<List<Map<String,Object>>>`

But `Map<String,Object>.class` doesn't compile, and `Map.class` doesn't allow me to have a `DataAccessResult<List<Map<String,Object>>>` as result type.

I mean :

```
DataAccessResult<List<Map>> x = executeQuery("Select * from table",Map.class, (Object[]) null);
DataAccessResult<Map<String,Object>>> y = (DataAccessResult<Map<String,Object>>>) x;
```

provoke a cast error
and `DataAccessResult<List<Map<String,Object>>> x = executeQuery("Select * from table",Map.class, (Object[]) null);` doesn't work either..

What could be the correct syntax?

Thanks!

Comment: Would `Map<String,Object>.class` do the trick?

Comment: Nope, it doesn't compile...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: you can not really do it. At least not in normal Java syntax. There are workarounds however.

The first is, you just explicitly specify `X` on the caller side this way:

```java
protected <X> DataAccessResult<List<X>> executeQuery(final String query, Object... args)

this.<Map<String, Object>>executeQuery("Select * from table");
```

You could also pass in an *object* instead of a class, that can "carry" the generic parameters:

```java
protected <X> DataAccessResult<List<X>> executeQuery(final String query, X prototype, Object... args)

executeQuery("Select * from table", new Map<String, Object>());
```

Both of these require no additional work, but are admittedly clumsy. The third option is to introduce a replacement for the `Class<T>` construct, which can carry generic parameters. This would word like this:

```java
protected <X> DataAccessResult<List<X>> executeQuery(final String query, JavaType<X> type, Object... args)

executeQuery("Select * from table", map(String.class, Object.class));
```

Where JavaType could look like this:

```java
public class JavaType<T> {
    public static <K, V> JavaType<Map<K, V>> map(Class<K> keyType, Class<V> valueType) {
        new JavaType<Map<K, V>>();
    }
}
```

This `JavaType<T>` class can be then extended with normal classes, lists, whatever you need. It could even carry the necessary class objects if you need them for reflection.

Comment: I like the first solution, dislike the second one (I don't like to create a useless object just to get this working) and I definitely love the last one! Thank you!